# Extract specific data from an output of shell command in Ansible

Tags: linux, unix, ansible

I would like to create a playbook that extract the `used` space for `/boot` through the shell command `df -B MB`.
For this example, the playbook will show `358MB` for the controller node.

I would like to know how to filter the `server_info.stdout_lines` in order to get the desired result.
I believe that we can do it with the `regex_search` filter.

```yaml
 - hosts: all
      gather_facts: True
      become: True
      tasks:
        - name: show used space on /boot
          shell: "df -B MB"
          register: server_info

        - debug:
            msg: "{{ server_info.stdout_lines }}"
```

```
TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [control] => {
    "msg": [
        "Filesystem          1MB-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on",
        "devtmpfs                1458MB    0MB    1458MB   0% /dev",
        "tmpfs                   1488MB    1MB    1488MB   1% /dev/shm",
        "tmpfs                   1488MB   10MB    1478MB   1% /run",
        "tmpfs                   1488MB    0MB    1488MB   0% /sys/fs/cgroup",
        "/dev/mapper/cs-root    19267MB 6268MB   13000MB  33% /",
        "/dev/sda1               1064MB  358MB     706MB  34% /boot",
        "tmpfs                    298MB    1MB     298MB   1% /run/user/42",
        "tmpfs                    298MB    1MB     298MB   1% /run/user/1000"
    ]
}
ok: [ansible2] => {
    "msg": [
        "Filesystem          1MB-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on",
        "devtmpfs                1458MB    0MB    1458MB   0% /dev",
        "tmpfs                   1488MB    0MB    1488MB   0% /dev/shm",
        "tmpfs                   1488MB   10MB    1478MB   1% /run",
        "tmpfs                   1488MB    0MB    1488MB   0% /sys/fs/cgroup",
        "/dev/mapper/cs-root    19267MB 6264MB   13003MB  33% /",
        "/dev/sda1               1064MB  360MB     704MB  34% /boot",
        "tmpfs                    298MB    1MB     298MB   1% /run/user/42",
        "tmpfs                    298MB    1MB     298MB   1% /run/user/1000"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why not just get used only for boot from the start? Like `df -B --output=used /boot` or something like that.

Comment: @KamilCuk you are right the command would do the required task but i would learn how to use the  `regex_search` to extract data

Comment: If you are going to use a shell command rather than a fact (which would probably by the recommended Ansible way), then you should do the shell command limiting it to what you need already, as proposed above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typical [x/y problem](https://xyproblem.info) (although it is easy to answer since you have given your root requirement i.e. get used size on a mount point).

You don't have to use `shell` to get that information. It's all available in the target machine facts (just make sure you did not disable fact gathering with `gather_fact: no` on your play).

The example below is for `/boot/efi` on my system. Just put it back on the actual mount point you want to target in the `selectattr` filter.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    mount_point: /boot/efi

  tasks:
    - vars:
        device_info: "{{ ansible_mounts | selectattr('mount', '==', mount_point) | first }}"
      debug:
        msg: "Used size on {{ mount_point  }} is {{ (device_info.size_total - device_info.size_available) | human_readable }}"
```

gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Used size on /boot/efi is 29.98 MB"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: thank you so much, this sounds very useful and practical. but  i see a difference between the `df` command result  `706MB`  and the playbook `672.86 MB`

Comment: I'm quite sure that `df -h` will give a result almost equal. If you really need to have the same result as `df -B MB` you will have to make the calculation yourself rather than using the `human_readable` filter

Comment: Ansible, and the information as you gather it from @Zeitounator's answer is more accurate, yours assume that 1000 = 1MB, while 1MB is actually 1024: > _Units are K,M,G,T,P,E,Z,Y (powers of 1024) or KB,MB,... (**powers of 1000**)._, italic text is from the manual of `df`.